# Is there an excel function to make a spine chart (Public Health England Profiles)

Tags: excel

[image]

I am trying to create this kind of range graph (Public Health England is calling it a "spine graph". Is there a way to create this? The website allows us to export a raw data which includes value, lower CI (95.0 limit), upper CI (95.0 limit) for England, Region and local authority.

https://fingertips.phe.org.uk/profile/health-profiles/data#page/1/gid/1938132701/pat/6/par/E12000007/ati/202/are/E09000008/iid/90366/age/1/sex/1/cat/-1/ctp/-1/yrr/3/cid/4/tbm/1

https://fingertips.phe.org.uk/documents/PHDS%20Guidance%20-%20Spine%20Charts.pdf

Comment: This is a site for programming questions. For general Excel questions, please try asking at https://superuser.com/.

Comment: And do try to include a screencap of the chart in your question, otherwise the question becomes useless once the link goes dead

Comment: You could approximate it using conditional formatting with a narrow column width

Comment: Or search for box and whisker.